# Symfony2: Retrieve entity and modify it ==> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-170' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: symfony

I have an entity and I would like to change some values.

So

1. I retrieve my entity
2. I change values
3. I persist my entity and I flush

... But I have this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-170' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Here the code

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="entity")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Bundle\Entity\EntityRepository")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"date" = "ASC"})
 */
class Entity
{
      /**
      * @var integer $id
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      */
     private $id; 
     // ...
}
```

I retrieve my entity like this:

```
function get(){
       $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('E')
        ->select ('E')          
            ->where('(E.type=:type) AND (E.m = :id)')
            ->setParameter('type',  $pType)
            ->setParameter('id',  $pMediaId)
        ->getQuery();
        return $query->getResult();
 }
```

And persit

```
$entity = $this->em->get(); // I have the correct value
entity->setTitle('My new title');
$this->em->persist($entity);

$this->em->flush();
```

Please help me

See ya

Sam

Comment: Is seems that you have defined 2 ID fields in your entity. What is the second one ?

Comment: it doesn't... I have seen in my structure table that I have only ONE id fields and it is the only primary key

Comment: what field is data "170" for ?

Comment: it's the id of entity that I want to update

Comment: What is '1' ? Cause the duplicate entry is caused from a composed Primary Key, composed of '1' and '170' ....

Comment: I dont know.  How can I do to know what 1 for?

Comment: I have a ManyToOne with another entity. Is it possible it is this ?

Comment: Thank you PC ! You hep me. I have found the problem. I was just becase I add an object into my manytoone association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I add an entity to my **ManyToOne**  relationship...

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? If you mark your own answer as correct, you really should describe in detail how you solved the problem so that others can benefit from it, not just a half sentence implying where the problem was.

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to persist the entity. you only need to flush the changes, persisting tries to create a new record.

EDIT:

Direct from the SF2 Documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Updating an object involves just three steps:

1. fetching the object from Doctrine;
2. modifying the object;
3. calling flush() on the entity manager

Notice that calling $em->persist($product) isn't necessary. Recall that this method simply tells Doctrine to manage or "watch" the $product object. In this case, since you fetched the $product object from Doctrine, it's already managed.

I have run into similar issues when editing entities and taking out the persist has fixed the issue. Im sorry this was not the case this time.

Comment: That's false, EntityManager::persist() processes as well INSERT as UPDATE. It depends on the entity it handles (new object or coming from EntityManager request).

Comment: I agree with PéCé. In your controller when in your updateAction you persist your object. So it can't be EntityManager::persist() processes. Althought I doubted, I have tested this solution, but still have the error chasen.

Comment: @PéCé respectfully it is not false, persisting is not needed in editing the entity as you can see by my edit. Sam, im sorry that wasnt the fix for you. Glad you found it.

Comment: Chasen. I have Seen in the Symfony doc you CAN Forget the persist entity process. So you are right. Thanks

Comment: @chasen : Good to know that !

Answer (score 1):

```
function get(){
   $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('E')
    ->select ('E')          
        ->where('(E.type=:type) AND (E.m = :id)')
        ->setParameter('type',  $pType)
        ->setParameter('id',  $pMediaId)
    ->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

This method will always return as object collection even though you are filtering by ID. So if you need to retrieve single row then you must need to call `$query->getSingleResult()` instead of `$query->getResult()`. I guess this is the problem here as you are trying to update as

```
$entity = $this->em->get(); // I have the correct value
entity->setTitle('My new title');
$this->em->persist($entity);

$this->em->flush();
```